# Is there a way to use a module imported from the main file in other modules that are imported by the main file?

Tags: python, python-module

I am trying to make a module that adapts to other modules in the file where **name** == '**main**' gives True.
Let's say that i have a module that prints text with rich if it is imported and normally if not.
I do not want to import rich from the module, instead i would want to do something like this:

module.py:

```
    import sys

    def print2(x)
        if 'rich' in sys.modules:
            rich.print(x)
        else:
            print(x)
```

main.py:

```
    import rich
    import test2

    test2.print2('Hello world')
```

but this dosent work.
Is there a solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`import rich` defines the variable `rich` as a global variable in `main.py`, however `rich` is not defined as a global variable in `module.py`, as each module has a different global namespace.
therefore if you need to call `rich` from within `module.py`, you have to call it from within `sys.modules` as following:

```py
import sys

def print2(x)
        if 'rich' in sys.modules:
            sys.modules['rich'].print(x)
        else:
            print(x)
```